# Finding the sum of even-valued terms in a Fibonacci sequence where the sum of those terms does not exceed 5 million

Tags: javascript

the code below is set to perform the sum of even valued terms in a Fibonacci sequence. The first part creates the terms so the first 2 ones and the addition from that. The second part creates an array that stores all these terms. The third part seeks out only the even terms and adds them and a condition is added to only do such for those less than 5 million.

```js
//The below creates Fibonacci sequence as we know it
var memo = [0, 1];
function fib (n) {
    if(memo.length-1 < n) {
        memo[n] = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
    }
    return memo[n];
}

// creates array with elements from function that takes the index as argument while a given condition holds
function takeWhile (fromFunc, cond, arr=[]) {
    var n = arr.length;
    var val = fromFunc(n);
    if(cond(val)) {
        arr.push(val);
        return takeWhile(fromFunc, cond, arr);
    }
    return arr;
}
   //adds all the numbers in the sequence below 5 million
var sum = 
    takeWhile(fib, n => n < 5000000)
   //the below line makes sure that only the even numbers in the sequence are added
    .filter(n => n%2==0)
    .reduce((acc, c) => acc+c, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: what does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the index, not the value for filtering.

```
.filter((_, i) => i % 2 == 0)
```

```js
function fib(n) {
    if (memo.length - 1 < n) memo[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    return memo[n];
}

function takeWhile(fromFunc, cond, arr = []) {
    var val = fromFunc(arr.length);
    if (!cond(val)) return arr;
    arr.push(val);
    return takeWhile(fromFunc, cond, arr);
}


var memo = [0, 1],
    sum = takeWhile(fib, n => n < 5)
        .filter((_, i) => i % 2 == 0)
        .reduce((acc, c) => acc + c, 0);

console.log(sum);
console.log(...memo);
```